# Are "She is being rude" and "She is behaving rudely" roughly the same?

Tags: word-usage, word-choice, phrase-usage, phrase-choice

We know that "**to be**" verb is not normally used in any continuous tenses except when it means "**to behave**"

> [To be](https://www.ldoceonline.com/dictionary/be) :
>
> 6 [linking verb] to behave in a particular way
>
> He was just being rude.

---

After "**to be**", we can have an adjective. However, after "**behave**", we have to use an adverb as in "*[The doctor behaved very **unprofessionally**](https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/behave?q=behave)*".

My question is

Are "**She is being rude/unprofessional...**" and "**She is behaving rudely/unprofessionally...**" roughly the same?

**Or is there any difference between them?**

Comment: Only that **being rude** could refer just to speech.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, they are roughly the same. However, if you'd like to focus on the differences,

> She is *being* rude

It's a general way of discussing rudeness, and could apply to either actions or speech. A default assumption might be speech, because that's a common way of being rude.

> She is *behaving* rudely

Since it mentions the word "behavior", it seems to indicate her actions are involved.